# Dentrix G4 dat file

Tags: dentrix

I am trying to read data from appt.dat file for Dentrix G4 version. It seems that the schema has changed from G3 to G4 version. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 5):

I first like to introduce myself (per moderator request) as a Dentrix Developer Partner. I do not work for Dentrix, I'm an authorized 3rd-party Dentrix developer. I also like to state very clear that is not my intention to get any profit out of the information I like to share with you.

Reading data from a Dentrix G4 database or older versions is really complicated. In fact is not officially supported by Dentrix. However you can possibly manage by using an Hex Editor or something, but you really have no easy way to do it with an API or an SDK since Dentrix doesn't provide those for G4 and older versions. On top of that, using any method of reading the database without Dentrix's approval could fall into a HIPAA violation and you could get yourself in real trouble.

Also, Dentrix G5 just came out early in 2012 and they implemented encryption to the database itself so at this point a Hex Editor would be out of the question, but not everything is lost.

On the other hand, on Dentrix G5 the database structure changed again, but this time for good. Dentrix G5 finally uses an SQL database engine that allows you to query the data in a much easier way.

The engine they use is ctreeACE SQL.

Much better, they now provide APIs and SDKs for developing purposes which allows you full access to the database in read-only mode.

If you like to get a hold on an API, I recommend you to go to http://ddp.dentrix.com for more information.

Once again, I like to state very clear is not my intention to get any compensation from sharing this out since I don't get any benefit from it anyways. Reason for this is the API implies a cost (is not free).

I truly hope you find this information useful.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Trixi from Open Dental might be able to dump it to a comma delimited file.. If you can find it. =) Someone also wrote a ODBC driver but the site is now down.. Most likely a former dentrix employee, as he posted from American Fork.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the ctreeACE SQL engine and write data, by SQL insert or something?

Comment: Looks like you really can't since the SDKs appear to be limited to read-only access. Therefore an SQL Insert, Update, Delete or anything that needs write access into the raw data is restricted.
However I've heard Dentrix is considering to implement SQL Stored Procedures that will allow write access to specific tables into the database. So that means an SQL Insert will still be restricted but in the future you may have write access via SQL Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing. The data is stored in fixed width columns, fixed length rows. Once you identify your layout, you can then parse the data. I think this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMeghA82kSk) is me going through a sample SoftDent database, or Dentrix G4. On the bright side, once you figure it out for Dentrix G4, the definitions for Easy Dental is nearly identical.

For Dentrix G4, there is no ODBC driver, everything Dentrix uses to read data is embedded into Dentrix. There is no way to access the data short of parsing it. Data is stored in a mixture of binary and ASCII and will have to be converted for each record.

It will end up being something like this:

```
{
  "file": "APPT.DAT",
  "Offset": 2989,
  "LineLength": 332,
  "data": [
    {
      "Column": "AppointmentId",
      "StartingPosition": 1,
      "ColumnWidth": 3,
      "DataType": "LEInt"
    },
    {
      "Column": "Date",
      "StartingPosition": 5,
      "ColumnWidth": 4,
      "DataType": "DTXDate"
    },
    {
      "Column": "RscType",
      "StartingPosition": 9,
      "ColumnWidth": 1,
      "DataType": "LEInt"
    },
    {
      "Column": "OperatoryId",
      "StartingPosition": 10,
      "ColumnWidth": 4,
      "DataType": "String"
    }
}
```

If you are only trying to get access to your own data, ReminderDental's database integration can export the top 16 tables to an SQLite database. If you are trying to develop a commercial solution, then hopefully you will find this helpful.